# Transferring JavaScript objects to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

The object within an object contains variables such as "name", "amount", "amountType", and "cal". The strings on those variables should be transferred through loop as several row in the given HTML table. Each variable should be on its own cell.

I already made one row and made 4 cell for the name, amount, amount type, and calorie columns. Then, I tried to transfer the objects elements inside the cell using the index of the object.

```js
let mealObj = {
  menu1: {
    menuName: "Steak",
    ingr1: {
      name: "Butter",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "2",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "10",
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Parsley",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "1",
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Garlic",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "20",
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Soy Sauce",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "20",
    },
    ingr5: {
      name: "Beef",
      ingrType: "meat",
      amount: "3/4",
      amountType: "lbs",
      cal: "200",
    },
    ingr6: {
      name: "Salt",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/8",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "0",
    },
    ingr7: {
      name: "Pepper",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/8",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "2",
    },
  },
  menu2: {
    menuName: "Spaghetti",
    ingr1: {
      name: "Ground Beef",
      ingrType: "meat",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "lbs",
      cal: "300",
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Olive Oil",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "3",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "50",
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Onion",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "30",
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Garlic",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "5",
    },
    ingr5: {
      name: "Tomato Paste",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "2",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "60",
    },
    ingr6: {
      name: "Dried Oregano",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "5",
    },
    ingr7: {
      name: "Red Pepper Flakes",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "2",
    },
    ingr8: {
      name: "Red Wine",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "200",
    },
    ingr9: {
      name: "Tomato",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "28",
      amountType: "ounce",
      cal: "150",
    },
    ingr10: {
      name: "Black Pepper",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "2",
    },
    ingr11: {
      name: "Basil Leaves",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "5",
      amountType: "pcs",
      cal: "5",
    },
    ingr12: {
      name: "Pasta",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "12",
      amountType: "ounce",
      cal: "250",
    },
    ingr13: {
      name: "Parmesan Cheese",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "75",
    },
  },
  menu3: {
    menuName: "Sushi",
    ingr1: {
      name: "Nori",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "6",
      amountType: "sheet",
      cal: "10",
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Sushi Rice",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "3",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "150",
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Salmon",
      ingrType: "meat",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "lbs",
      cal: "220",
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Cream Cheese",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "4",
      amountType: "oz",
      cal: "75",
    },
    ingr5: {
      name: "Avocado",
      ingrType: "fruit",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "pc",
      cal: "60",
    },
    ingr6: {
      name: "Soy Sauce",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "10",
    },
  },
  menu4: {
    menuName: "Burger",
    ingr1: {
      name: "Beef",
      ingrType: "meat",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "lbs",
      cal: "300",
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Egg",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "large",
      cal: "50",
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Onion",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "30",
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Garlic",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "2",
      amountType: "pcs",
      cal: "10",
    },
    ingr5: {
      name: "Bread Crumbs",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "60",
    },
    ingr6: {
      name: "Worcestershire",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "5",
    },
    ingr7: {
      name: "Salt",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "2",
    },
    ingr8: {
      name: "Pepper",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "4",
    },
    ingr9: {
      name: "Buns",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "4",
      amountType: "pcs",
      cal: "150",
    },
    ingr10: {
      name: "Mayonnaise",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "60",
    },
    ingr11: {
      name: "Ketchup",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "cup",
      cal: "25",
    },
    ingr12: {
      name: "Lettuce",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "4",
      amountType: "pcs",
      cal: "100",
    },
    ingr13: {
      name: "Tomato",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "large",
      cal: "45",
    },
    ingr14: {
      name: "Red Onion",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "4",
      amountType: "slices",
      cal: "50",
    },
  },
};

let ingrTable = document.getElementById("ingr-table");
let totalRowLength = ingrTable.rows.length;

let row = ingrTable.insertRow(totalRowLength);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

cell1.innerHTML = mealObj[0][1].name;
cell2.innerHTML = mealObj[0][1].amount;
cell3.innerHTML = mealObj[0][1].amountType;
cell4.innerHTML = mealObj[0][1].cal;
```

```html
<table id="ingr-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Ingredient</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Amount Type</th>
            <th>Calorie</th>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating the `mealObj` as an `array` while it's an `object` and also you're not looping, so your code only runs once.

Below you can find a code that works for the first Menu (Steak). You might need to account for multiple meals by creating multiple tables.

```
let ingrTable = document.getElementById("ingr-table");
let totalRowLength = ingrTable.rows.length;
for(key in mealObj.menu1) {
    if(key == "menuName") {
        continue;
    }
    item = mealObj.menu1[key] 
    

    let row = ingrTable.insertRow(totalRowLength);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = item.name;
    cell2.innerHTML = item.amount;
    cell3.innerHTML = item.amountType;
    cell4.innerHTML = item.cal;
}
```